# How can I evaluate a View context variable as a Template variable in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'd like to pass a context variable from a view into my template to direct what the template should display.

I have a context list variable `column_headers` that dictates the number of columns in a list page table, along with the header text that should be used.

```
context['column_list'] = [
    _('Animal'),
    _('Owner'),
    _('Reason'),
    _('Time'),
    _('Vet'),
    _('Status')
]
```

I'd like to include a related list variable that tells the template which variable to include for each cell in the corresponding column, for example:

```
context['cell_vars'] = [
    'patient',
    'client',
    'reason',
    'start_time',
    'attending_staff',
    'status'
]
```

such that the variable `FOO.client` would appear in the `'Owner'` column, and `FOO.attending_staff` would appear in the `'Vet'` column, etc.

Doing this allows me have a single list.html page to handle all of my lists.

So, my question is whether this is a good idea, and if so, how would I go about evaluating a 'string' presented as a context variable i.e.

```
{% for row in rows %} #loop over list data
    {{ row.attending_staff }} #work fine, but...
    {{ row.SOME_VARIABLE_THAT_HAS_VALUE_OF_'attending_staff' }} #doesn't
{% endfor %}
```

So, if `x='attending_staff'` I need to be able to evaluate the variable `row.x` such that it actually evaluates `row.attending_staff`

The use case for this is very defined and involves display logic only (not data retrieval since the data is already in the loop variable `row`) so IMO could be a good fit for a template.

It would allow me to have a single 'list.hml' template to handle pretty much all of my lists, rather than what I have currently which is 10 x foo_list.html pages, all being very similar to each other (table structure, looping logic, icons, links, css class names etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think [custom tags or filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) would be a solution

e.g.: the following

```
@register.filter
def settings_value(name):
    return getattr(settings, name, "")
```

could be used in the templates like

```
{% load your_filters %}
{{ "MY_SETTINGS_NAME"|settings_value }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do it in this way? Or maybe you don't have option for that:

```
# Python script
context['column_list'] = [
    _('Animal'),
    _('Owner'),
    _('Reason'),
    _('Time'),
    _('Vet'),
    _('Status')
]

context['cell_vars'] = [
    'patient',
    'client',
    'reason',
    'start_time',
    'attending_staff',
    'status'
]

g_context = zip(context['column_list'], context['cell_vars'])

# HTML
{% for column, var in g_context %}
    {{ column }}
    {{ var }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it what you're asking for?